# How to validate a variable number of start and end dates on a web page using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am validating start date is less than end date using jquery.
It works if i know the no.of start and end date elements.
But my problem is in my form there can be many start and end dates.
How should i do it for example given below.

```
Start Date <input type="text" id="t1_sdate_0">
End date <input type="text" id="t1_edate_0">  

Start Date <input type="text" id="t1_sdate_1">
End date <input type="text" id="t1_edate_1">


Start Date <input type="text" id="t2_sdate_0">
End date <input type="text" id="t2_edate_0">  

Start Date <input type="text" id="t2_sdate_1">
End date <input type="text" id="t2_edate_1">
```

I want to do something like below

```
          $('#sDate').datepicker(
                {gotoCurrent: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', yearRange: '1850:2050',maxDate:'0'
                ,
                 onSelect: function(selected) {
                    $("#eDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
                }});

        $('#eDate').datepicker(
                {gotoCurrent: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', yearRange: '1850:2050',maxDate:'0'
                ,
                 onSelect: function(selected) {
                    $("#sDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);
                }});
```

Comment: show us how you are currently validating them

Comment: Please don't post that much code in a comment.  Please _append_ your answer using the "edit" link.

Comment: @jena84 i have provided a demo.check it.

Comment: Thanks for the code...but i do not want to click validate button,i mean when i first select end date say 7th dec 2012 then if i go to start date then all the dates after 7th should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function Validate(){
      var isVallid = true;

    $("input[id*=sdate]").each(function(){          
            var nextInput = $(this).next();   
            console.log(nextInput);
            if (Date.parse($(this).val()) > Date.parse(nextInput.val()))
                  isVallid  = false;
      });

    return isVallid ;
}
```

check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rpKF8/4/)

Answer (score 0):

While i've not encountered a performance problem using jQuery's each() function, for some cases its [less performant](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices).

Consider the following function:

```
function Validate(){
    var arr = $("input[id*=sdate]");
    for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++)
    {
        var splittedId = arr[i].id.split('_');
        var matchingInput = $('input[id*=edate_' + splittedId[splittedId.length - 1] + ']');
        if (Date.parse($(arr[i]).val()) > Date.parse(matchingInput.val()))
                return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The implementation has two advantages on the other answer. Firs one is that it's independent to DOM elements positions, meaning that you could still add elements between a pair of matching inputs without loosing functionality (scalability). Second you may not notice if the number of date inputs are small, but in a rather extreme case, say 1000 inputs, this implementation returns with the first invalid input pair and the perfomance difference may not pass unnoticed.

Check the implementation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a0viedo/R7MRJ/).

Happy coding!